# Menu design not uniform for all resolutions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

i am trying to implemnt a app in i wrote code to draw APP Menu .In my application Menu is drawing at top_center of the layout for all resolution as shown in below images.

[image: For Low resolution]
[image: For 10" Tablet]
[image: For 10" tablet in another Orientation]

But i need **Buttons** at horizontal&vertical center of layout for all resolutions and screens.

Currently i am using below code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/myLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2E9AFE"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Choose an Option"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

"

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bDefSms"
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blackbutton"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sms"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:text="AAA"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSMS"
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blackbutton"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/defsms"
        android:text="BBB"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bMMS"
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/blackbutton"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mms"
        android:text="CCC"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bMail"
        android:layout_width="256dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/blackbutton"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/email"
        android:text="DDD"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me.

Comment: you need to make different layouts for different screen size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add one line to your linearlayout：

```
          android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

wHey why don't you use RelativeLayout as a root like this and use attribute layout_centerHorizontal and layout_centerVertical to true:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/myLinear"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#2E9AFE"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this will help.